# List multiplication

Tags: f#

Is there any built-in function that multiplies all elements of a list with another?

i.e

```
let xList = [1..30]

let yList = [1..30]
```

would give:

```
[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)..ect]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is called a cross-product or Cartesian product of lists. The easiest way to construct it is to use sequnce expressions - you can simply iterate over the two lists and yield all pairs:

```
let prod = [ for x in xList do
               for y in yList do
                 yield x,y ]
```

If you want to use higher-order functions, then you can use `List.collect`:

```
xList |> List.collect (fun x -> 
    yList |> List.map (fun y -> x, y))
```

For every value `x` from the `xList`, the lambda function generates a new list (such as `[(x,1); (x,2); ... (x, n)]`). The `List.collect` function then concatenates all these generated lists.

Answer (score 8):

I'm starting to sound like a salesman :), but
[FSharpx](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx) has a function `List.lift2` that does that (parameterized by a function, similar to Haskell's `liftM2`).

So with FSharpx it's `let prod = List.lift2 tuple2 xList yList`

(`tuple2` is a tuple constructor, also included in FSharpx)

EDIT: just in case, I'd like to point out that I'm not suggesting to get a dependency on FSharpx just for this... of course you could just use a list comprehension or even just define lift2 and tuple2 yourself, they're trivial:

```
let inline lift2 f (l1: _ list) (l2: _ list) = 
    [ for i in l1 do
        for j in l2 do
            yield f i j ]

let inline tuple2 a b = a,b
```

FSharpx has a lot of built-in goodies like this.